# What is difference in unit between energy-full vs charge_full?

Tags: hardware, power-management, battery

I have 2 different results of maximum batery energy:

`upower -i $(upower -e | grep -i bar) | grep energy`

```
energy:              18.061 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         33.4021 Wh
energy-full-design:  50.7296 Wh
energy-rate: 7.30384 W
```

So from `upower` I get that maximum energy could be ~33.5 Watt*hour. But from `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/{charge_full,charge_full_design}`

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full:
2186000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design:
3320000
```

I get number `2186000`, what unit is it? Joule? But that is not the same with the above `33.5*60*60 == 120600J`. So why is it different. Also what is `energy-rate` (7 Watt)? Is it battery performance right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the kernel documentation these values are in µAh (microampere-hour):

```
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  Charge/Energy/Capacity - how to not confuse  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
~                                                                       ~
~ Because both "charge" (µAh) and "energy" (µWh) represents "capacity"  ~
~ of battery, this class distinguish these terms. Don't mix them!       ~
~                                                                       ~
~ CHARGE_* attributes represents capacity in µAh only.                  ~
~ ENERGY_* attributes represents capacity in µWh only.                  ~
~ CAPACITY attribute represents capacity in *percents*, from 0 to 100.  ~
~                                                                       ~
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt

The relationship between Watt*hours and Amp-hours is described here: https://www.rc-electronics-usa.com/battery-electronics-101.html